# ValueError: too many values to unpack in fmin_l_bfgs_b

Tags: python

I have the following code that is running to run xfoil to get me optimum values of weights in an aerofoil.

```
def four_dim_opt(x0, weight_limits, cl, file_path, xfoil_path):
opt_out = fmin_l_bfgs_b(run_xfoil_wcl, x0, args = (cl, file_path, xfoil_path), bounds =    weight_limits, epsilon = 0.01, approx_grad = True)
return opt_out
```

where run_xfoil_wcl is a functionreturning coefficient of drag values (float).

The error I keep getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
four_dim_opt(x0, weight_limits, 1.2, file_path, xfoil_path)
File "H:/appliedlab4 - Copy(2).py", line 157, in four_dim_opt
opt_out = fmin_l_bfgs_b(run_xfoil_wcl, x0, args = (cl, file_path, xfoil_path), bounds =     weight_limits, epsilon = 0.01, approx_grad = True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\lbfgsb.py", line 166, in fmin_l_bfgs_b
l,u = bounds[i]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: What is `weight_limits`? You seem to be passing too many values into it.

Answer (score 1):

The `weight_limits` argument to [scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html) is causing the error and it should be either `None` or a list containing two elements:

> weight_limits - (min, max) pairs for each element in x, defining the bounds on that parameter. Use None for one of min or max when there is no bound in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

What are you passing to four_dim_opt as your `weight_limits`? The value for weight_limits gets passed to bounds, which is then accessed in the line in your error message:

```
l,u = bounds[i]
```

This means weight_limits is expected to be a list or tuple, and each item in the list should ALSO be a list or tuple (holding exactly two values).